# Remove opening bracket with next closing only

Tags: regex

I have this case for example:

> Some important information \hl{to check out} later. textbf{test}.

I want to remove only brackets staring with \hl and closes closing to get:

> Some important information to check out later. textbf{test}.

I can remove the opening string with `/\\hl{/g`. That will remove "\hl{" but how to also remove the closest closing bracket?

I was trying something like this `\\hl{[^}]*\K}` but this only removes the closing bracket. I am so close and have no idea how to combine those two together?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern:

```
\\hl\{([^}]*)\}
```

..and replace with `\1`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vftTrh/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```
\\hl        # Matches "\hl" literally.
\{          # Matches an opening curly bracket.
([^}]*)     # Matches zero or more character other than closing curly brackets 
            # and captures them in group #1.
\}          # Matches a closing curly bracket.
```

Then, you use `\1` to replace everything that was matched with what was captured in group #1.

Answer (score 0):

in python, this worked for me: re.subn('\\hl{|} ','',x), where x="Some important information \hl{to check out} later. textbf{test}."